# SQL Server 2008 Page/Row Compression Thoughts

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, compression

Have other people here played with [SQL Server 2008 Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx) at either the page or the row level on their datasets much?  What have your impressions been on performance both speed and disk-space wise?

Has anyone ever seen compression demonstrably hurt performance?

On some of our huge fact tables we've been playing around and noticing that compression can make a hugely beneficial query speed difference on both tables and its indexes.  It's also been saving a lot of disk space (~50% on some data).  Our hardware setup is severely disk/io bound relative to the processor and compression so far seems like a trivially easy performance win for us.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Old question, but from experience, a simple rule of thumb is:

- for non-BLOB data row-store *page* compression ratio is between 3 and 4 times
- for non-BLOB data column-store compression ratio is between 9 and 11 times

---

Linchi Shea articles seem to be behind a login now....

Linchi Shea has posted some interesting articles on this topic:

- [SQL Server 2008 Page Compression: Compression ratios with real-world databases](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/05/11/sql-server-2008-page-compression-compression-ratios-from-real-world-databases.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Data Compression: Impact of Data Distribution](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/06/20/sql-server-2008-data-compression-impact-of-data-distribution.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Page Compression: Performance impact on table scans](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/05/16/sql-server-2008-page-compression-performance-impact-on-table-scans.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Page Compression: Performance impact on inserts](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/05/12/sql-server-2008-page-compression-performance-impact-on-inserts.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Page Compression: Using multiple processors](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/05/05/sql-server-2008-page-compression-using-multiple-processors.aspx)

This might also be of interest:

- [Best Practices for Data Warehousing with SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc719165.aspx)

The [SQL Server Storage Engine blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/) also has a few interesting posts on Compression.

Comment: Found link on Wayback: https://web.archive.org/web/20080518011433/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2008/05/16/sql-server-2008-page-compression-performance-impact-on-table-scans.aspx